# Macro to rename multiple functions together

Tags: scheme, racket

Following statement can be used to rename "expt" function to "power":

```
(define-syntax power (make-rename-transformer #'expt)
```

Multiple functions can be renamed using above statement multiple times.

Can one rename multiple functions in one go, e.g. rename +, -, * and / to add, sub, mul and div, respectively?

Comment: Consider using `rename-in` or `rename-out` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure,

```
#lang racket

(define-syntax-rule (renamer [old new] ...)
  (begin (define-syntax new (make-rename-transformer #'old)) ...))

(renamer [expt power] [+ add] [- sub])
```

But as @AlexisKing says, it's more convenient to use [`rename-in`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._rename-in%29%29).

```
#lang racket

(require
  (rename-in racket/base
    [expt power]
    [+ add]))

(power 3 3) ;; 27
```